# Secondary menu not showing up in wordpress footer

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am a beginner trying to create my own wordpress theme.

I have two nav menus one for the header one for the footer but the secondary one for the footer is not showing up. My code is currently as shown below.

**- Functions.php**

```
function base_theme_setup(){

 add_theme_support('menus');

 register_nav_menu('primary','Primary Header Navigation');
 register_nav_menu('secondary','Secondary Footer Navigation');

}

add_action ('init', 'base_theme_setup');
```

**- footer.php**

```
<footer>
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'secondary')); ?>

</footer>

<?php wp_footer (); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not to sound too simplistic but have you selected the Secondary Menu, within WordPress and assigned it Menu Items?

Comment: Yes I have. It all looks fine on the backend it just doesn't show up on the site.

Comment: Try changing `init` to `after_setup_theme`.

Comment: gave it ago but to no effect:(

Comment: Go to the site in question and do Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it.

Had some useless undeleted code at the bottom of my index.php. Once deleted the problem went away.

So went from this

```
<?php

 if( have_posts() ):

    while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

       <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h3>
       <div class="thumbnail-img"><?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?></div>
       <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
       <small>Posted on: <?php the_time('F j,Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>, in <?php the_category(); ?></small>
       <hr>

<?php   endwhile;

 endif;

 ?>

<?php

            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

            endwhile; 
?>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

to this

```
<?php 

 if( have_posts() ):

    while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

      <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>

      <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

      <small>Posted on: <?php the_time('F j,Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>, in <?php the_category();?></small>

      <hr>

<?php   endwhile;

 endif;

 ?>
 <?php get_footer();?>
```

Thanks for everyones tips!

Comment: Great to hear you resolved your issue and posted your resolution here. :-)  Just to reiterate my earlier comment, do change `init` to `after_setup_theme` as a matter of good practice and to ensure you do not experience any issues at a later date.  Best of luck with your Theme Developments/Learning curves!

Comment: Maybe this was producing some error. In the development process always use 
define('WP_DEBUG', true); in wp-config.php file

Comment: @MahfuzulHasan:  Good tip.  Sometimes, the basics can be overlooked! :-)

Comment: Thanks for all your tips!